# C: how to return a struct literal without mentioning its type name?

Tags: c, gcc, type-inference

We can return struct literal from a function by casting anonymous literal initializer to the return type:

```
struct foo f() {
    return (struct foo) { .bar = 42 };
}
```

Is it possible without mentioning `struct foo` anywhere in the initializer? Separate declaration:

```
struct foo result = {
    .bar = 42
};
return result;
```

will not do, as it still explicitly mentions the `struct foo` type.

Is it possible to get the return type of enclosing function with `typeof`? I tried:

- `return (typeof(#__func__())) { .bar = 42 };`
- and `return (__auto_type) { .bar = 42 };`,

but apparently C's type inference doesn't go outside of a single expression.

I'm writing a preprocessor macro and would like to avoid the extra argument for the type.

`gcc` specific solutions are welcome.

Comment: No C doesn't work that way.

Comment: Re “casting anonymous literal initializer”: That is not a cast. A compound literal has the grammatical form `(type) { initializers }`, but it is its own thing, not a cast, anymore than the `(type)` in `sizeof (type)` is a cast.

Comment: Victor Sergienko, "Is it possible without mentioning struct foo anywhere in the initializer? " is unclear.  `struct foo` is **not** mentioned in the _initializer_.  `struct foo result` is the definition.  `= {  .bar = 42 }`  is the initializer with no `struct foo`.  Perhaps re-word.

Comment: Victor Sergienko, "I'm writing a preprocessor macro " --> consider posting the coding goals of that task "How do I do X?", (albeit) in another question, rather than this limited approach of "How do I do X using Y?"

Comment: Victor Sergienko "Is it possible to get the return type of enclosing function ...?" --> It is possible to use `_Generic` to match `f` to a finite set of options and then use that result to define the type of `result`.

Comment: There's no problem getting the return type of the call to a function with no arguments. (If it takes argument, you need to know what types they are in order to write the call, which probably defeats the purpose.) But `__func__` doesn't provide a mechanism to call the current function. It provides its name as a string literal, which is a very different thing. You can't call a string in C, although the language syntax doesn't prevent you from writing the call. (The compiler should warn you, though.)

Comment: Also, the preprocessor `#` ("stringify") operator turns an arbitrary token into a string literal. It does not turn a string literal into a token. If you apply `#` to a string literal (which is a token), you get a new string literal which produces the stringified string literal. In other words, if you stringify the token `foo`, you get the token `"foo"` (a string literal), and if you then stringify that token, you would get the string literal `"\"foo\""`, which would print out as `"foo"`. So that's definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It is not possible.  Both a declaration (6.7.6) and an initialization of compound literals requires a type specifier (6.5.2.5, 6.7.9).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [latest public C11 standard draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) at the time of writing, "6.5.2.5 Compound literals" (which are struct initializers):

> A postfix expression that consists of a **parenthesized type name followed by a brace-enclosed list** of initializers is a *compound literal*.

(bold emphasis is mine).

Indeed, it has nothing to do with type cast, except for similar syntax.

I believe, this is the only way in C standard to specify `struct` literals.

Comment: You should reference the latest specification, C17 (N2176), at this point, and C23 when it's finalized (IMHO).

Comment: @AllanWind Agree, C17 is better, yet scant difference in C11, C17.